# Can I alter a column from VARCHAR to VARCHAR FOR BIT DATA without affecting the existing data

Tags: database, db2

I am using following query to change the column type , which seems fine on my sample table

ALTER TABLE temp
ALTER COLUMN Col SET DATA TYPE VARCHAR(15) FOR BIT DATA
go

Before using it on my production data , i want to make sure that it won't create any issue with existing DATA.

Comment: Hi @user3391293! I don't know how much you are used to these conventions, but if one of those answers helped you to solve your problem it would be nice to mark it as 'accepted'. This would help others who have the same problem like you. Moreover you and the answerer get some reputation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr:

Altering a column from `VARCHAR(15)` to `VARCHAR(15) FOR BIT DATA` will **not** modify the *data* in the table.  However, the representation of the data you get back will change.

---

When you insert a row into a table with a `VARCHAR()` column, DB2 converts the data you insert from the client application's code page to the database's codepage (if they are different), and then writes the data in the table.  When you query that data, DB2 takes the string of bytes from the `VARCHAR()` column and produces the characters using the database codepage.

When you use `FOR BIT DATA`, DB2 writes the stream of data into the column without any codepage.  It just writes the stream of bytes.  When you query the data, DB2 returns a stream of bytes as a hex string.

So, if you insert `'Hello'` into the `VARCHAR(15)` column, internally this is stored as 5 bytes:  `x'48656C6C6F`' (assuming UTF8 codepage).  When you query this column, DB2 converts this 5 bytes back to `'Hello'` according to the UTF8 codepage.

However, if you alter the column to `VARCHAR(15) FOR BIT DATA`, then when you query the data, DB2 will return the unencoded byte string:  `x'48656C6C6F'`

Thus:  While the data itself doesn't change, what you get when you query the column *will* change.

Final note:  Changing a column to `VARCHAR(15) FOR BIT DATA` is a one-way operation.  Once you strip  the code page associated with the data in the column, DB2 will always return the data as a stream of bytes, even if you alter the column and drop the `FOR BIT DATA` clause.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to say that it won't create any issue. The issues depend on your current data model: current table DDL. You have to check many things:

- Storage
- Transactions
- Row overflow
- Routines that use the column
- ...

Thus, it is better to test that change in a non-production db with the production data, in order to verify that it won't have any impact.